# TRIM: Permissions error creating a record through Web service API

Tags: trim, hp-trim

HP TRIM 8.0

I am trying to create a record using Service API and getting this error message, but I can successfully create a todo item, Missing any permission settings?

```
2016-07-22 10:15:36,661 [20] ERROR ServiceStack.DtoUtils - ServiceBase<TRequest>::Service Exception
HP.HPTRIM.SDK.TrimException: You do not have create record access for this Record Type.
at HP.HPTRIM.SDK.Record..ctor(RecordType recordType)
at HP.HPTRIM.Service.RecordConstructor.Construct(Database database, TrimObject trimObject)
at HP.HPTRIM.Service.Extensions.FindOrCreateTrimObject(TrimMainObject trimObject, Database database)
at HP.HPTRIM.Service.TrimObjectUpdater`1.<getTrimMainObjects>d__0.MoveNext()
at HP.HPTRIM.Service.TrimObjectUpdater`1.update(T request, IRequest requestContext, Action`1 action)
at HP.HPTRIM.Service.RecordDocumentServiceBase.DoPost(Record request)
at HP.HPTRIM.Service.RecordDocumentService.Post(Record request)
at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1.Execute(IRequest request, Object instance, TRequest requestDto)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Error clearly states the user does not have permission to create the particular record type. Make sure the apppool user is added as trusted user.